# newline for Arabic or urdu string

Tags: c#, localization, multilingual, arabic, text-processing

```
        string s = "";

        s += "پاکستان کے وزیراعظم نواز شریف نے یقین دہانی کرائی ہے کہ صحافی حامد میر پر قاتلانہ حملے :TV";

        s += "\n\r"+"بی بی سی اردو کا آفیشل ٹوئٹر اکاؤنٹ۔:BBC Urdu's";

        xrLabel1.Text = s;
```

---

but its show worried output like

```
 پاکستان کے وزیراعظم نواز شریف نے یقین دہانی کرائی ہے کہ صحافی حامد میر پر قاتلانہ حملے :GEOبی بی سی اردو کا آفیشل
ٹوئٹر اکاؤنٹ۔:BBC Urdu's
```

---

i want some thing like (same like my code)

```
پاکستان کے وزیراعظم نواز شریف نے یقین دہانی کرائی ہے کہ صحافی حامد میر پر قاتلانہ حملے :GEO
بی بی سی اردو کا آفیشل ٹوئٹر اکاؤنٹ۔:BBC Urdu's
```

---

i think its new line problem any suggestion or solution's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need a right to left embedding character (RLE) at the beginning of the line to show RTL and LTR words correctly.

- U+202A:   LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING (LRE)
- U+202B:   RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING (RLE)
- U+202D:   LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE (LRO)
- U+202E:   RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE (RLO)
- U+202C:   POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING (PDF)

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls

```
char rleChar = (char)0x202B;// RLE embedding 
text = rleChar + text;
```

Comment: پاکستان کے وزیراعظم نواز شریف نے یقین دہانی کرائی ہے کہ صحافی حامد میر پر قاتلانہ حملے :GEOبی بی سی اردو کا آفیشل
ٹوئٹر اکاؤنٹ۔:BBC Urdu's

Comment: man finally i found solution from another forum but its close to your answer you just told me about RTL but we it require alos newline and return/enter feed after my 1 day effert i made my new code patch now i done it but thxs for you answer

Comment: @sms247 please share your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) and see if that helps.

However I think that the problem is the label, try changing the Text Wrap or other properties related to rows and also to AutoSize.

If that fails use 2 labels.

Comment: thxs for quick reply but i already used 
s += Environment.NewLine;
and                                                                    s += System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine);
but both are not working

Answer (score 1):

i used unicode(U+000A and U+000D) character for \n  and use RLE(U+202B) for each line now its work fine for me
here is the detail of Unicode you urdu and Arabic
Finish typing the Arabic word and add a space after it (this space separates the embedded text from the Arabic text to its right).
Insert special character U+000A (to Feed Newline an Arabic character).
Insert special character U+000D (to Feed RETURN/ENTER an Arabic character).
Insert special character U+200F (to render the preceding space an Arabic character).
Insert special character U+202A (to begin the left-to-right embedding).
Insert special character U+202B (to begin the Right-to-LEFT embedding).
Insert another space (to separate the embedded text from the Arabic text that will continue to its left).
Change the keyboard to e.g. English and type the left-to-right word.
Insert special character U+202C (to restore the bidrectional state to what it was before the left-to-right embedding).
Change the keyboard back and continue writing in Arabic.